# How to save a "self" variable in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, self

In python, inside a class, it appears that when I save a "self" variable into another one, if I edit the new variable, the "self" is also edited:

```
    undropped_lines = self.flagged_lines
    print self.flagged_lines
    del undropped_lines[0]
    print self.flagged_lines
```

How should one avoid this trait in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because lists are mutable and when you say `undropped_lines = self.flagged_lines` you are just pointing a new name at the same instance.

If you want a copy use `undropped_lines = self.flagged_lines[:]`

Answer (score 3):

This is because `undropped_lines` and `self.flagged_lines` are pointing to the same data. Think of it as two different "names" pointing to the same entity.

You can get around this by creating a shallow copy of the list when assigning to `undropped_lines`. Something like:

```
undropped_lines = list( self.flagged_lines )
```

Comment: Almost word for word 3 seconds apart +1

Comment: @Trengot: Indeed mate, +1 to you too :)